# Zeki TBDG773B Doesn't Recognize External SD card

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, tablet, internal-sd

I have a Zeki TBDG773B which isn't allowing apps to install because of a lack of space.

Error:

> Insufficient storage
>
> This device doesn't have enough space to download "App Name".  Consider deleting apps or content you no longer need and try again.

I believe the build has an issue with recognizing the difference between the internal storage and the external SD card.  Perhaps an issue with mounting the card correctly?

Zeki TBDG773B

- "Internal Storage" 849MB Used / 143MB Free (just system apps)
- "On SD Card" 2.1MB Used / 4.5GB Free (I believe this is the internal SD
  card)
- "SD Card" (External) Available 14.91GB

About:

- Android Version: 4.4.2
- Kernel Version: 3.10.33
- Build number: KOT49H.Zeki.20140923.v001

No updates available.

Any suggestions to allow app installations to the external SD card?

Alternatively, any way to make the external card recognized as sdcard0 and the internal card recognized as sdcard1 as it seems the system wants to work with "0"?

Comment: What is the format of the sd card?

Comment: @programming Easiest way to check that would be?

Answer (score 1):

The error is most likely the card is in not supported format or it is a not supported size (such as some phones only support 32 GB SD cards).

(Windows Version)The way to check the format is to plug it in to a computer then go to `File Explorer > Right click on the sd card > Properties` Then look at the file system. If the card file system is not NTFS then you have to format it. Go to `File Explorer > right click on the sd card > Format` on the format screen select file system to *NTFS*. **NOTE:all data on sd card will delete**. Leave all setting default except for ntfs format. Then click format.

Plug it into your device and it should mount and work properly. If any thing is unclear just comment.

Comment: I'm working on testing this now.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Been so long since I needed a PC SD card reader, I'm trying to find one...